# How can I retrieve form data out of request.POST in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I want to get a form data sent through request.POST. The data is in a form of dictionaries inside a list. Here is the html form and ajax request:

```
<form class="passwordUpdateForm" novalidate="" name="passwordUpdate" action="" method="" 
                              id="passwordUpdateForm">
                                {% csrf_token %} 

                                <div class="md-form md-outline mb-3">
                                  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="oldPass">current password </label>
                                  <input type="password" id="oldPass" class="form-control" name="oldPassword" placeholder="*********" value="">
                                </div>

                                <div class="md-form md-outline mb-3">
                                  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="newPass">new password </label>
                                  <input type="password" id="newPass" class="form-control" name="newPassword" placeholder="*********" value="">
                                </div>

                                <div class="md-form md-outline mb-5">
                                  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="newPassConfirm">confirm new password </label>
                                  <input type="password" id="newPassConfirm" class="form-control" name="newPasswordConfirm" placeholder="*********" value="">
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-4"> change password  </button>

                              </form>


<!-- to change user password  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#passwordUpdateForm').on('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

         
          // to get form data  
          var formData =  $(this).serializeArray();
          var formData = JSON.stringify(formData);
          alert(formData);
          // submit ajax request 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'passwordReset' %}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: {
                    'form_data': formData,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    var message = $('#flashMessage').html('');
                    message.append('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">'+'<strong>'+'sorry {{first_name}} </strong>'+ data +'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'+'<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'+'</button></div>');
                }
            });

    });

</script>
```

The backend view function is as follow:

```
def passwordReset(request):

# process form data
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:

    user = request.user

    oldPassword = request.POST.get('oldPassword')
    newPassword = request.POST.get('newPassword')
    newPasswordConfirm = request.POST.get('newPasswordConfirm')


    form_data = request.POST.getlist('form_data')
    if form_data:
        form_data = json.loads(form_data)

    print('You are here')
    print(oldPassword)
    print(form_data)
```

the output of oldPassword and form data is empty.

My question is: How can I retrieve all form data from request.POST all at once for further process?

Comment: Hi use [$(this).serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it will pass your fields in key value pairs and no need to use stringify see if that works .

Comment: I did that before. but nothing was changed. I could send all form data as a form of key,value pair. but I do not how to retrieve them in django view function

Comment: is there any error in browser console ? are value pass successfully ?